# Not able to create responsive table in wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have used the Elementor plugin in my WordPress site and created a table but I am not able to make it responsive.

https://aujmsr.com/most-viewed-articles/

Comment: Please share more details. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: How did you create your table?